# Using a networked drive I am trying to access a folder using a variable. I only get the contents of the previous folder.

Tags: cmd

I have a location on a networked drive that gets a folder with the current date for every file.  I am trying to access this location by temporarily mapping the drive (Net Use) and then using the date to fill in the folder name.

When I execute the code it is set to the previous directory. (A DIR listing will bring up the contents of that folder and the rest of the code to move files puts them in that location)

Any ideas?
Thanks

```
PAUSE
REM This is to move the Export file to the FTP Site. 

Set Year_Mo_Da=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%

time /t

net use z: \\Network.com\Validation\2014
REM \%Year_Mo_Da%  -- This is the folder name 

cd /d z:\%%Year_Mo_Da%%
DIR

Copy Z:\*FileName_*.* Y:\NewLocation\TEST
net use z: /delete

time /t
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing directories but then copying from the root after all.  @foxidrive removed the backslash but perhaps it wasn't noticed when you made your change?

```
cd /d z:\%%Year_Mo_Da%%
```

...you're in the subdirectory

```
Copy Z:\*FileName_*.* Y:\NewLocation\TEST
```

...but you copied from the *root* of Z: after all.

This would work (quotes can't hurt of course but for this example aren't required unless your filename contains spaces):

```
Copy Z:*FileName_*.* Y:\NewLocation\TEST
```

BTW I tend to use `pushd` and `popd` so I don't have to know the drive letter.  Don't know if that helps you or not but you don't have to `net use /d` either, or care if `Z:` is in use for something else.

```
pushd \\Network.com\Validation\2014\%Year_Mo_Da%
Copy *FileName_*.* Y:\NewLocation\TEST
popd
```

Comment: I had an issue with my date formatting that was causing an error for me.  Figured it out and everything is functioning smoothly now.  Thanks for the info in CMD! I will be using pushd and popd all the time now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need doubled percents here:

```
cd /d "z:\%Year_Mo_Da%"
```

Depending on what you need to do - this may be the next command:

```
Copy "*FileName_*.*" "Y:\NewLocation\TEST"
```

Comment: I removed the double percents and put the copy part in double quotes.  I am getting the same issue.  It picks up the previous folders contents. It is like it does not recognize the folder made up of the variable date.